# Cosa significa "sito oscurato"?

Tags: meaning

Navigando su Internet, sono andata a finire su un sito web nel quale appariva la scritta "sito oscurato" e nient'altro. Cercando il [significato di "oscurare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/oscurare/), ho trovato questa accezione:

> Per estens., nel linguaggio giornalistico, disattivare un ripetitore radiofonico o televisivo mediante interventi tecnici, da eseguirsi in seguito a un provvedimento dell’autorità, allo scopo di bloccare la ricezione delle trasmissioni e impedire di conseguenza, in modo indiretto, alle stazioni emittenti di proseguire temporaneamente la loro attività o di trasmettere determinate notizie.

Significa questo che quel sito web era disattivato in modo che non si potessero vedere più i contenuti?

Comment: La tua interpretazione è corretta... anche il Treccani è rimasto indietro rispetto al normale uso delle parole. La denominazione *sito oscurato* direi che esiste da almeno una decina d'anni.

Comment: Mi sorprende che la pagina fosse in Italiano più che altro, come dice DaG nei commenti è il provider che reindirizza verso queste pagine (quindi implicherebbe un provider Italiano). Probabilmente in questo caso hanno modificato il sito vero e proprio.

Comment: Hai ragione, @kos. Penso che possa essere dovuto al fatto che in uno dei miei profili Google ho scelto la lingua italiana: si tratta di profittare di tutte le occasioni possibili per imparare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esatto, la dicitura "sito oscurato" indica che il sito è stato disattivato. Tipicamente questo succede quando il sito conteneva materiale coperto da copyright (per esempio siti di streaming) e quindi violava le leggi in materia, per cui è stato chiuso dalle autorità competenti.

L'uso del verbo *oscurare* in questo senso ha un connotato metaforico, pari a quello che hai trovato e che si applica al gergo giornalistico.

Comment: D'accordo su tutto, e aggiungerei che forse certe volte, più che essere disattivato il sito, la magistratura richiede ai provider del proprio paese di non far accedere gli utenti al sito (che quindi di per sé continua a essere attivo in altri paesi). Mi ricordo che per un certo tempo se si cercava di accedere dall'Italia a The Pirate Bay, appariva una schermata fissa, credo della Procura di Bergamo.

Comment: Certe volte un sito è oscurato perché il gestore è in ritardo col pagamento del servizio di hosting :)

Comment: *Di talché operandosene*?

Comment: Ho ripristinato la versione originale della risposta, che non aveva assolutamente niente che non andasse.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider, ti prego di far caso al fatto che un conto è intervenire su una domanda o risposta altrui perché contiene un oggettivo errore linguistico o fattuale o qualcosa che può infastidire, e tutto un altro è intervenire per riformularla come l'avresti formulata tu, nonostante la versione di partenza fosse impeccabile.

Answer (score 2):

***[L'oscuramento](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscuramento_(informatica))*** (informatico):

> - in genere, serve per rendere nascosto o non visibile o non riconoscibile qualche cosa. ***In informatica, si intende la tecnica usata per quei siti che non rispettano le leggi di un paese,*** genericamente per violazioni di copyright, pedofilia, incitamento alla violenza o diffamazione, ma nel caso di false democrazie o vere e proprie dittature, anche di siti sgraditi al regime politico vigente (come ad esempio in Cina).
> - ***In questi casi il riferimento verso quel sito viene cancellato e/o bloccato o reindirizzato l'instradamento da un nodo, detto anche router di internet verso un computer della polizia, non rendendo più visibile il sito.***

Wikipedia

Comment: Certe volte un sito è oscurato perché il gestore è in ritardo col pagamento del servizio di hosting :)