# È corretto usare l'imperfetto quando, invece, dovrebbe usarsi il presente?

Tags: word-meaning

Secondo @DaG ([Cosa significa "sito oscurato"?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6299/cosa-significa-sito-oscurato/6302#comment12309_6302)) questo scritto sarebbe impeccabile.

> Esatto, la dicitura "sito oscurato" indica che il sito è stato disattivato. Tipicamente questo succede quando il sito conteneva materiale coperto da copyright (per esempio siti di streaming) e quindi violava le leggi in materia, per cui è stato chiuso dalle autorità competenti.

Secondo me, invece, 'conteneva' e 'violava' sono sbagliati perché:

- non rendono la contestualità dell'atto di oscuramento con la presenza, in quel preciso momento, di materiali illegali nel sito, come se l'oscuramento è avvenuto dopo che i medesimi materiali sono stati rimossi,
- né comprendono l'opzione che quei materiali siano ancora presenti nel sito dopo l'atto di oscuramento, come se l'oscuramento corrispondesse ex sé al toglierli,

di talché io avrei usato 'contiene' e 'viola'.

> ... questo succede quando il sito *contiene* materiale coperto da copyright (per esempio siti di streaming) e quindi *viola* le ...

C'è qualcuno disposto a discutere questa questione?

Comment: In passato, il sito "conteneva materiale ...": adesso non contiene niente di tutto questo appunto perché è oscurato.

Comment: No, un sito oscurato può continuare a contenere ciò che conteneva, solo che non si vede più. Un po' come mettere un coperchio su uno scatolo, ciò che c'è dentro resta — anche se non più visibile.

Comment: L'hai notata la petitio principii nel titolo della tua domanda, Elberich?

Comment: A me la frase sembra perfettamente corretta, dopo tutto l'imperfetto è un tempo adatto a rappresentare la contemporaneità nel passato. Le obiezioni mi paiono più una questione filosofica su cosa significhi che un sito "contenga" dei materiali e, onestamente, un po' di lana caprina. Un sito è in ogni caso un concetto astratto.

Comment: La frase è corretta sia grammaticalmente che semanticamente. Però devo darti un punto sul fatto che l'imperfetto non la faccia suonare benissimo. Penso che usare il presente o il passato prossimo l'avrebbe fatta suonare meglio.

Comment: Piccola precisazione: solitamente i siti che hanno problemi di copyright vengono "oscurati" a livello di DNS dai provider italiani. In particolare, semanticamente, un sito oscurato c'è ancora e contiene tutto quello che deve contenere. È solo che hanno reso più difficile/scomodo accederci dall'Italia, tutto qui.

Comment: Se poi vogliamo essere ancora più precisi, *tutti* i siti contengono materiale coperto da copyright. :)

Answer (score 5):

Effettivamente c'è una carenza nella coordinazione dei tempi.

Tuttavia l'uso del presente implicherebbe una correlazione diretta fra causa ed effetto che non trova riscontro nella realtà dei fatti:

> I siti vengono oscurati quando contengono materiale coperto da copyright.

significa che tutti i siti contenenti materiale pirata dovrebbero essere oscurati.

Visto che la causa reale non è la presenza di contenuti illegali ma la decisione di un autorità giudiziaria di limitare l'accesso al sito, lascerei l'imperfetto variando leggermente la frase:

> Tipicamente questo *può succedere perché* il sito conteneva materiale coperto da copyright...

In questo modo sottolineiamo che il problema non è la presenza al tempo attuale di contenuti illeciti, ma che questi erano probabilmente presenti nel momento in cui il sito è stato oscurato.

Answer (score 3):

Il 1° del mese il sito *conteneva* materiale illecito.

Il 2 del mese viene oscurato.

Il 3 del mese, nel chiuso della sua inaccessibilità, il sito può contenere o meno quel materiale; è irrilevante.

Scrivere che un sito *è stato disattivato* (passato) perché *contiene* (presente) del materiale illecito può far sembrare che lo si sia disattivato prima ancora che contenesse quel tal materiale, o comunque creare un senso di confusione nel lettore.

Comment: 'stato disattivato' appartiene al periodo precedente quello in questione. Qui 'conteneva' e 'violava' sono da correlare a 'succede', piuttosto.

Comment: Forse capisco il tuo ragionamento, @ElberichSchneider. Evidentemente interpretiamo in modo diverso il collegamento tra i due periodi. Io, in quel ragionamento, nel passaggio «...il sito è stato disattivato. Tipicamente questo succede quando...», leggo il pronome “questo” in luogo di “che il sito sia stato disattivato”, che quindi richiede un passato riferito allo stato del sito precedente e contemporaneo alla disattivazione. Tu, se capisco bene, aggiorni il “questo” al significato di “che il sito sia disattivato”, al presente; è questo che intendi?

Comment: Preferirei “Questo succede perché il sito conteneva…”; “quando” introduce una contemporaneità (“questo succedeva quando Berta filava”).

Comment: @DaG 'Tipicamente questo succede quando' è una frase senza tempo, giustapporgli un imperfetto è tanto sbagliato quanto sbagliato è dire, p.e., 'Dio vede e provvede quando fuori pioveva.' (-1 from me)